# Make a get request to download a pdf from url-to-pdf-api

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, pdf, download

Hi Guys I need your help.

I need to save a screenshot or a pdf from a website

I am relatively new on this, I don't know if I can use this url-to-pdf-api to make a get request to download or save the file on a DataBase, I am using Javascript/Vue and Python and I don't know how to do it

I'm trying to do this

```
this.$http.get('https://url-to-pdf-api.herokuapp.com/api/render?url=http://google.com').then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    }, function(response) {
        alert("error")
    });
```

But after that, I don't know what to do

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to store the text in a file like so:

```
f = open("yourFileName.txt", "a")
f.write("Insert text here")
f.close()
```

And i recommend you to use [fpdf](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf/) to save and edit pdf files